# Apply forces such that a satellite reaches a given point in space

Tags: artificial-satellite, physics, acceleration

I'd like to find out a strategy for solving the following *simplified problem*.

- A small spherical craft at $t=0$ has a position and velocity vectors $\mathbf{x_0}, \mathbf{v_0}$ in a zero gravity environment.
- It has one outward-pointing thruster that can vector in any direction by rotating it's spherical shape using internal attitude control.
- Each second the craft can emit one pulse resulting in a standard, small $\Delta v$ via one *outward-pointing thruster* that can vector in any direction by the craft rotating it's spherical shape between pulses using internal attitude control.
- The craft must be moving with a speed (absolute value, not directional velocity) less than $\mathbf{v_m}$ at the position $\mathbf{x_1}$.
- ideally a least-time solution is sought, but a procedure that yields many solutions is still helpful because they can be compared and the optimal solution selected.

How would I go about trying to solve this problem? Are there existing solutions or methodologies?

Comment: Are you making any considerations to fuel usage or mass or do you just assume that each pulse just changes the velocity?

Comment: I'm sure I read a question like this recently

Comment: what is it's rotational rate and acceleration - can we assume it can rotate to any position in the time between thrusts? Can we assume the thrusts are sufficiently short duration that they can be treated as impulses, otherwise can the acceleration be treated as constant during the thrust. Is $v_m$ known to be larger than $\delta v$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It isn't really about space exploration -- It's a geometry question.

Comment: The simplest way of doing this is to zero the velocity (isosceles triangle with current velocity as the base and $\Delta v$ as the sides) then point at the target and thrust. if $v_m$ is smaller than $\Delta v$ then another isosceles triangle is needed, and you need to adjust your aim by the distance travelled during the first thrust.

Comment: This looks like a homework question, but without any indication of what work you have tried. Can you update your post with what you have tried and what bit you are unsure of.

Comment: @JCRM: [You did](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32667/apply-forces-such-that-satellite-reaches-a-given-point-in-space). satellites: deleting and reposting is not the correct way to get attention for a question. See https://space.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers for better ways.